# Fundamental theorem of algebra in an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and let $f(x)\in K[x]$.

Is it true that $f(x) = 0$ has $\deg f$ solutions in $\overline K$?

In particular, I am interested in solving $x^6 - 1=0$ in a field $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K)\neq 2,3$. I'm not sure why I've been given the characteristic here, or how it can help me.

I believe that the same argument of FTA applies, i.e., we may write $f$ as $a_{\deg f}\prod_{k=1}^{\deg f}(x-\alpha_k)$ with $\alpha_k\in \overline K$, and that since we are in an integral domain, the result follows.

Comment: Did you mean the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "FTC"--it is usually an abbreviation for "the fundamental theorem of calculus", but I don't see how that would apply here.  Perhaps you meant "FTA"--the "fundamental theorem of algebra", which asserts the degree $n$ polynomials have $n$ roots?

Comment: Of course! I don't know how I made that mistake.

Comment: The "elliptic curves" tag?

Comment: @paulgarrett fixed

Comment: There is no such thing as the FTA in an algebraically closed field, the FTA is specific to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that

$$\begin{align*}
x^6-1 &= (x^3-1)(x^3+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1).
\end{align*}$$

Note that we cannot assume that $\overline{K}=\Bbb{C}$. However, we can use what we know about the roots of $x^6-1$ in $\Bbb{C}$ to make a guess about what will happen in $\overline{K}$, and then we just have to prove that our guess is correct.

Let $\theta$ be a root of $x^2-x+1$. Then we will show that

$$x^6-1=\prod_{i=1}^6(x-\theta^i).$$

Since $\theta$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$, we have that $\theta^2=\theta-1$.

Also, since $\theta$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$, and $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1$, we have that $\theta$ is also a root of $x^3+1$. Hence $\theta^3=-1$.

From the fact that $\theta^2=\theta-1$ and $\theta^3=-1$, we get the following (as you can check):

$$\theta^4=-\theta,$$
$$\theta^5=1-\theta,$$
$$\theta^6=1.$$

With these relations, you can check that each of the following hold:

$$(x-\theta)(x-\theta^5)=x^2-x+1,$$
$$(x-\theta^3)=x+1,$$
$$(x-\theta^2)(x-\theta^4)=x^2+x+1,$$
$$(x-\theta^6)=x-1,$$

and having verified the above equations, we have verified that

$$x^6-1=\prod_{i=1}^6(x-\theta^i).$$

The restrictions on $\text{char}(K)$ are used to show that the roots $\theta,\theta^2,\ldots,\theta^6$ are distinct.

For example, $\theta=\theta^4$ iff $\text{char}(K)=2$. Note that if $\text{char}(K)=2$, then $x^6-1=(x^3-1)^2$.

Also, note that the following are equivalent:

$$\theta=\theta^3.$$

$$\theta=-1.$$

$$-1\text{ is a root of }x^2-x+1.$$

$$\text{char}(K)=3.$$

If $\text{char}(K)=3$, then $x^6-1=(x^2-1)^3=(x-1)^3(x+1)^3$.

If $\text{char}(K)\ne2,3$, then we can show that the roots of $x^6-1$ are distinct by using the following:

**Fact:** Let $F$ be a field, let $p(x)\in F[x]$ and let $\lambda$ be a root $p(x)$. Then $\lambda$ is a multiple root of $p(x)$ iff $\lambda$ is a root of $p'(x)$, where $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$ (defined formally).

Let $p(x)=x^6-1$, then $p'(x)=6x^5$. So if $\text{char}(K)\ne2,3$, then $GCD\left(p(x),p'(x)\right)=1$, so the roots of $p(x)$ are distinct.

Comment: Thank you! what about $\overline{K}^{\boldsymbol{\color{red}\times}}$?

Comment: If I'm understanding your notation correctly, $\overline{K}^{\times}$ is just the non-zero elements of $K$. Note that $\theta\ne0$ since $\theta$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$. Since $\theta\ne0$ we also have $theta^i\ne0$ for $1\le i\le6$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot we are in a field.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for posting this question!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you direct me to a resource which explains the general theory behind results such as $x=x^4$ for characteristic 2?

Comment: In this problem, $\theta^4=-\theta$. So $\theta^4=\theta$ iff $-\theta=\theta$ iff $2\theta=0$. And this is true iff $\text{char}(K)=2$, because $\theta\ne0$.